# wget batch linux file

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I am trying to download images from a manufacturer's site using `wget`.  When I run the command from the shell it works fine. But when I run it from a file I am getting a placeholder file.

Here is the command:

```
wget --wait=2 --output-document=1000.jpg 'http://distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage.cfm?prod=8cb7afa6-73bf-4f9f-b251-38dc652779c9&size=large'
```

Here is what it looks like in a file:

```
wget --wait=5 --output-document=1101.jpg 'http://distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage.cfm?prod=4d41b2ff-90a4-40c1-9159-2780cd642244&size=large'
wget --wait=5 --output-document=1102.jpg 'http://distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage.cfm?prod=5e88f32e-48f2-40db-bdbd-53624448392d&size=large'
wget --wait=5 --output-document=1103.jpg 'http://distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage.cfm?prod=59292a17-ae6f-49df-a028-0a9f71686f80&size=large'
```

I can't figure out why it isn't working as a batch shell file.

Comment: It's probably something small that's tripping it. Check this page for more info though - http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Invoking

Comment: What does the placeholder contain? Are you invoking the script from the same shell where the direct call works? In particular, were the proxy settings the same?

Comment: What is "Doesn't work"? What exactly is the output when it "Doesn't work"? How are you invoking it? Is this from a cron job? Are you passing it to a shell e.g. `bash foo.sh`? Are you executing by path e.g. `./foo.sh`?

Answer (score 1):

You know that you need to add an x (execute) flag on Unix to execute a shell script? Another common pitfall for DOS users is that for security reasons there is often no "." in the PATH Environment thus you need to run "./your-script" instead of just "your-script".

Concerning the she-bang mentioned in the other answer. At least on Linux /bin/sh is the default shell used if no she-bang is given inside the script. It is still good practice to always add one to all scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it here, and it worked fine. Do you have a she-bang line at the top?
`#!/path/to/shell`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: For bash it would be: #!/bin/bash

Comment: That depends on where _bash_ is located. On my box, it's /usr/local/bin/bash ;)

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/env bash` - most systems place `env` in /usr/bin, so it's pretty portable. The down side is that it's easy to intercept by adding a custom bash interpreter earlier in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Get the output from

```
which bash
```

and

```
which wget
```

then add the returned  path to bash at the top of your script with a hash bang(#!). i.e if which bash return /bin/bash then use.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then add the returned path for wget. example

```
/usr/bin/wget --wait=5 --output-document=1101.jpg 'http://distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage
```

finally make sure the script you have created is executable `chmod +x name-of-your-script`

If its not working still try adding -x to your script to get some debugging info.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```